# Why last array column looks like this?

Tags: php, arrays, file

Using file with this content:

```
1 2 3 4 5 0
6 7 8 9 10 0
11 12 13 14 15 1
16 17 18 19 20 1
```

I try this code to create 2d array and get last column:

```
<?php

$tab = array();
$lastColumn=array();
$file = file('test.txt');
foreach ($file as $item) {
    array_push($tab, explode(' ', $item));
};

foreach ($tab as $item) {
    array_push($lastColumn,end($item));
};
var_dump($lastColumn);
```

But last cloumn looks like this:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "0 " [1]=> string(3) "0 " [2]=> string(3) "1 " [3]=> string(1) "1" }
```

All values have string(3) and space after except last one (string(1) and no space after)

I need all values in last column without space and string(1). Someone can help me?

Comment: you aren't removing the line breaks and can't see them but they are there

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: remove  `\n` on each line, then explode

Comment: Works great, thaks

Comment: @Marcin If it "works great", please give charlietfl the green tick.  If it is anyway insufficient, please edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are line breaks in the file represented by `\n` that need to be removed.

Try changing :

```
foreach ($file as $item) {
    array_push($tab, explode(' ', $item));
};
```

To something like:

```
foreach ($file as $item) {
    array_push($tab, explode(' ', str_replace('\n','',$item)));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything you've described is commonly referred to as [*whitespace*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) in programming. That is, characters that exist in your string that aren't visible the way a character is.

PHP has a built in function dealing with this called [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) which includes all those characters:

> This function returns a string with whitespace stripped from the
>   beginning and end of str. Without the second parameter, trim() will
>   strip these characters:
>
> **" " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.**
>
> "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
>
> **"\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).**
>
> "\r" (ASCII 13
>   (0x0D)), a carriage return.
>
> "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
>   "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.

So

```
foreach ($tab as $item) {
    array_push($lastColumn,end($item));
};
```

becomes:

```
foreach ($tab as $item) {
    array_push($lastColumn,end(trim($item)));
};
```